# please help me remove content on paste event

Tags: ckeditor

I want to remove the format the content when user paste into ckeditor. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
    editor = e.editor;
    editor.on('paste', function (e) {
        editor.focus();
        editor.document.$.execCommand('SelectAll', false, null );
        editor.execCommand('RemoveFormat', editor.getSelection().getNative());
        editor.insertHtml('additional content');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText= true;` to config.js, that should solve your problem.

Comment: forcePasteAsPlainText strips a,ul,ol,li... (just to name a few) while the RemoveFormatting function does not.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by formating content before set value for textarea

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e){
    var editor = e.editor;
    editor.on('paste', function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append("<div id='tmpCt'>"+ editor.getData() +"</div>");
            $('#tmpCt div, #tmpCt p, #tmpCt a, #tmpCt span').removeAttr("style");
            $('#requiredDescription').val($('#tmpCt').html());
            $('#tmpCt').remove();
        }, 100);
    });
});
```